# How to show DatePicke/TimePicker dialog from Fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker

I have a Fragment where I have a FragmentTabHost and some tabs attached to it. Each tab is also a Fragment.Now, from any of them , I want to display DatePicker and Timepicker, then how will I show them using DialogFragment or any other method?

Answer (score 0):

try this code..

```
    public class student extends Fragment 
        {
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_main, container, false);
            return view;
            }
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        editdate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        showDatePicker();
                    }
                });
 edittime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       showTimePicker();
                    }
                });
        }


    private void showDatePicker() {
                  DatePickerFragment date = new DatePickerFragment();
                      /**
                       * Set Up Current Date Into dialog
                       */
                      Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
                      Bundle args = new Bundle();
                      args.putInt("year", calender.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                      args.putInt("month", calender.get(Calendar.MONTH));
                      args.putInt("day", calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                      date.setArguments(args);
                      /**
                       * Set Call back to capture selected date
                       */
                      date.setCallBack(ondate);
                      date.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
                     }

                     OnDateSetListener ondate = new OnDateSetListener() {

                      public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                        int dayOfMonth) {

                       edittext.setText(String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + "-" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)
                           + "-" + String.valueOf(year));

                      }
                     };
private void showTimePicker()
{
     //DatePickerFragment date = new DatePickerFragment();
     TimePickerFragment time= new TimePickerFragment();

     Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putInt("hour", calender.HOUR_OF_DAY);
      args.putInt("month", calender.get(Calendar.MONTH));
      args.putInt("minute", calender.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
      time.setArguments(args);


    time.setCallBack(ontime);
      time.show(getFragmentManager(), "Time Picker");

}

OnTimeSetListener ontime = new OnTimeSetListener() {

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        txt_time.setText(String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute));
    }
     };

            }
```

create two classes DatePickerFragment and TimePickerFragment

```
 public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
         OnDateSetListener ondateSet;

         public DatePickerFragment() {
         }

         public void setCallBack(OnDateSetListener ondate) {
          ondateSet = ondate;
         }

         private int year, month, day;

         @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
         public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
          super.setArguments(args);
          year = args.getInt("year");
          month = args.getInt("month");
          day = args.getInt("day");
         }

         @Override
         public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), ondateSet, year, month, day);
         }
        }
```

TimePickerFragment.java

```
  public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

        OnTimeSetListener onTimeSet;

        public TimePickerFragment() {

         }
        public void setCallBack(OnTimeSetListener ontime) {
              onTimeSet = ontime;
             }
         @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private int hour, minute;
        public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
              super.setArguments(args);
              hour = args.getInt("hour");
              minute = args.getInt("minute");

             }
         public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), onTimeSet, hour, minute, false);
             }
            }
```